# JPA merge will load latest version from persistence?

Tags: jpa, merge

Suppose a detached entity foo, its version is 10. Another user changed the Foo, and its version becomes 11 in database.

```
em.merge(foo)
```

Some JPA provider(e.g. Hibernate) will load the entity from persistence and copy changes of the detached foo to the entity(managed).  The entity of the same version or the newest version will be loaded? Throw Optimistic Lock exception at merge time or at flush time?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Vlad Mihalcea's blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/):

... to associate a detached entity to an active Hibernate Session, you can choose one of the following options:

1. Reattaching Hibernate (but not JPA 2.1) supports reattaching through
   the Session#update method.

   A Hibernate Session can only associate one Entity object for a given
   database row. This is because the Persistence Context acts as an
   in-memory cache (first level cache) and only one value (entity) is
   associated to a given key (entity type and database identifier).

   An entity can be reattached only if there is no other JVM object
   (matching the same database row) already associated to the current
   Hibernate Session.
2. Merging The merge operaration is going to copy the detached entity
   state (source) to a managed entity instance (destination). If the
   merging entity has no equivalent in the current Session, one will be
   fetched from the database.

The detached object instance will continue to remain detached even after the merge operation.

So if you're in the second case, and Session has no related managed entity, a call will be fired to retrieve a brand new entity. Since read is no transactional, you can't lock anything.

Comment: which version of the entity to be loaded? the newest version in database or the version of the detached entity?

Comment: It depends from what's in the current session. If there's no managed, which is first place jpa searches anything, it tries the db.

Comment: For the example above, if it is not managed, version 10 or version 11 will be fetched?

Comment: If I understood well, in the DB there's 11 ...so will be 11.

Comment: User made changes based on version 10, but if it loads version 11, will it cause unexpected results?